# Bootstrap 3 grid re-sizing issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So basically I am building a full screen food image grid using bootstrap 3. I have used container-fluid and the appropriate columns to define the width of my rows and breakpoints. Each of the columns contains a food image and uses the class - col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4

I didn't want a gutter between the images so I removed the left and right padding assigned to the column class which gives me the exact look I want. Now when I resize the grid, it all works fine. However in between screen widths 950px and 980px, the images have a gutter between them vertically. I am unsure whats causing this. Does anyone have an idea?

I have attached a few pictures to illustrate along with bootply

http://www.bootply.com/xXaaLRWKTL . It happens in this example around the tablet screen break point. Resize the window and take a look, you will see the gutter comes back at the break point

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLPp.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the example, it's because of the images.

The images have the class `img-responsive`, which sets the property `max-width: 100%`. Since that particular image's max width is 320px, the images itself stop at 320px (the actual div is acting as it should). Either use a bigger image, or remove the max-width property and set `width: 100%`.